# Debian, beeping while installing

Tags: debian, debian-installer

My PC beeps while I install Debian Wheezy and is stuck at the point

```
Copying data to disk...
```

Is this an error or a new "feature"?

I downloaded the latest version from [here](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/bt-hybrid/) and put the iso with the Linux Live USB Creator on a 4gb USB Stick.

Comment: Did you choose to format an existing partition?

Comment: Yes the partition was formatted.

Answer (score 2):

The beeping is supposed to happen, and you should not be concerned.

Your computer is probably not stuck at the "copying data to disk part", as writing to the disk takes time, especially when installing something as large as an operating system. This may take hours depending on your system, but know that this is normal behavior.

You may want to use the graphical install option as that can provide a reassuring progress bar.